# TFS 2010 restored database, TfsJobAgent cannot connect to database

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have a Team Foundation Server 2010 setup, in which I have TFS on one server and the databases on another.  Recently the server with the databases completely crashed and I had to replace it.  I restored the databases from backups, and changed the web.config file for tfs to point to the new server and most everything seems to be working.

I can connect to tfs, do checkouts/checkins, create work items, etc.  However, I cannot queue builds, and the event log is filling up with errors saying that TfsJobAgent cannot connect to the database.

I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a way to configure TfsJobAgent to point to my new database.  The event log details are below (TCOSRV1 is the machine running tfs, not the database server).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
Date (UTC): 7/11/2013 4:55:27 PM
Machine: TCOSRV1
Application Domain: TfsJobAgent.exe
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Service Host: 
Process Details:
  Process Name: TFSJobAgent
  Process Id: 3520
  Thread Id: 5304
  Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Detailed Message: There was an error during job agent execution. The operation will be retried. Similar errors in the next five minutes may not be logged.
Exception Message: TF246017: Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database. Verify that the server that is hosting the database is operational, and that network problems are not blocking communication with the server. (type DatabaseConnectionException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(Int32 errorNumber, SqlException sqlException, SqlError sqlError)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException sqlException)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(SqlException ex)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ExtendedAttributeComponent.ReadDatabaseAttribute(String attributeName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseConnectionValidator.ValidateDatabaseInstanceStamp(String configConnectionString, Guid configInstanceId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.DatabaseConnectionValidator.ValidateApplicationConfiguration(String configConnectionString, Guid configInstanceId, List`1 sqlInstances, String analysisInstance, String analysisDatabaseName, Boolean ignoreAnalysisDatasourceUpdateErrors, Boolean autoFixConfiguration, Boolean fullValidation, DatabaseVerificationDatabaseTypes continueOnMissingDatabaseTypes)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ApplicationServiceHost..ctor(Guid instanceId, String connectionString, String physicalDirectory, String plugInDirectory, String virtualDirectory, Boolean failOnInvalidConfiguration)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobApplication.SetupInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.JobServiceUtil.RetryOperationsUntilSuccessful(RetryOperations operations)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (type SqlException)
SQL Exception Class: 20
SQL Exception Number: -1
SQL Exception Procedure: 
SQL Exception Line Number: 0
SQL Exception Server: 
SQL Exception State: 0
SQL Error(s):

Exception Data Dictionary:
HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID = -1
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId = 20476


Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line tool you can run that preps the SQL server. Look here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252516(v=vs.100).aspx#ConfigNewSQL

You may want to read that whole article, especially the stuff about clearing the cache. Sounds like you already have most of it. Good luck!